# django.core.cache.lock doesn't work in a Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

I have the following (`tasks.py`):

```py
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.cache import cache

@shared_task
def test(param1: str) -> None:
    with cache.lock("lock-1"):
        print("hello")
```

When I do a `test.delay()`, nothing is printed, which makes me believe that there is something wrong with `cache.lock("lock-1")`.

I'm using Redis as my cache and Celery backend, and this is configured in `settings.py`.

What is wrong here? If `django.core.cache` cannot be used as a locking mechanism (to ensure that only one `test` runs at a time, what could be used instead?) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out why - turns out I didn't read the documentation.

Adding this worked:

```py
# https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html
@contextmanager
def redis_lock(lock_id):
    timeout_at = time.monotonic() + LOCK_EXPIRE - 3
    # cache.add fails if the key already exists
    # Second value is arbitrary
    status = cache.add(lock_id, "lock", timeout=LOCK_EXPIRE)
    try:
        yield status
    finally:
        # memcache delete is very slow, but we have to use it to take
        # advantage of using add() for atomic locking
        if time.monotonic() < timeout_at and status:
            # don't release the lock if we exceeded the timeout
            # to lessen the chance of releasing an expired lock
            # owned by someone else
            # also don't release the lock if we didn't acquire it
            cache.delete(lock_id)
```

Then, the lock statement became

```py
with redis_lock("lock-1"):
```